# Can Toshiba 660D run UBUNTU

Tags: 12.04

I want to buy toshiba 660d laptop and it's come without OS.
Can I run UBUNTU 12.04LTS on it?
How can I know before I buy it?

Comment: Did you check out the official [system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is Yes.  The AMD CPU is excellent, the display adapter is good, and its supported by Ubuntu.  Since the display adapter uses installed RAM , and it doesn't have dedicated RAM. I would recommend that you upgrade the RAM.  Toshiba says that the unit will handle up to 8GM RAM.

Comment: ...before buying I found Toshiba Europe site and there is something like big warning 'Toshiba recommend Win7' and on their forum evrybody are like 'toshiba doesn't support linux OS' and 'you are on your own with it'.....Maybe I will just chose ASUS with a Ubuntu sticker on it and end this....but thank's anyway